# What kinds of things can be an 愛機?

Tags: words

大辞泉 gives the following definition for 愛機【あい.き】:

> 日ごろ好んで使い、大事にしている写真機などの機器。また、愛用の飛行機。

Meanwhile, the 大辞林 第三版 gives the following definition:

> 使い慣れて，大切にしている写真機などの機器。また，愛用の飛行機。

Also, 明鏡国語辞典 (thanks, @snailboat) has:

> 飛行機・カメラなど、大切に使っている機械。

All three of these definitions appear to focus on cameras and airplanes (though they all do also have a など suggesting that other related things could also be called 愛機).

My question: is 愛機 only used for these particular devices? Would it be alright for me to call some other device (like a car or a computer or a razor) an 愛機, or would that sound weird? (Basically, I'm wondering why these definitions identify specific examples of devices rather than using a generic word like 機器.)

Comment: @Earthliŋ Well, I'm asking if there's some reason that all three of these definitions (sorry for the mix-up with 愛器) refer specifically to 飛行機 and カメラ/写真機 - is 愛機 mostly only used for those two things? If not, why do the definitions specifically refer to those two things?

Comment: I guess probably the limited scope of 機 words that would have sentimental value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is "anything that can be described by a word containing 機{き} and can justifiably be one's favourite".

As for airplanes, 飛行機 can be considered a type of 機, mostly because it's in the name. Otherwise, 機 is now more often used for 機器 or 機械, machines/devices.

I think that, instead of カメラ・写真機, the definitions might as well have referred to a smartphone, MP3-player, CD-player, walkman, or any other type of device, which fits into the category of being something someone uses for fun.

As for usage, ノートパソコン, スマホ, アイホーン, ミシン, etc. could all be 愛機, because they're all devices that can be used for pleasure.

A(n electric) razor is borderline and only valid, if your favourite thing in the morning is shaving while singing along with the radio.

Cars don't qualify, because there's no common word XX機, which can be used to describe a car. But, 自動**車** is a word for car and you can use 愛車.

Comment: Ah, okay, I wasn't picking up on the fact that it only works for things that can be called [something]機. That helps, thanks! I'll hold off on accepting for a while, in case others want to post answers.